# Identity Server to MVC client : Page Redirect After login

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

Im trying to authenticate MVC client using Identity server 4. When I try to login the page redirect is not redirect to My mvc application. The page is keep on loading..... and I didnt get any error also.

Note : When I debug my identity server project its look like authenticated. Issue only redirect back to my mvc client.

All my client settings are in Database.

```
redirect URI - "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"
Grant Type - "implicit"
ClientCoreOrgin - "http://localhost:6301"
postLogoutRedirectURI - "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc"
```

Issue in redirect Page uri : http://localhost:6100/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=brown_dashboard&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20api1%20api2%20api3&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636488490344995894.ZDI4M2M5YzgtODlmNS00Y2VlLWEwNmYtZGRjMmI5ZTFjMWRhMTFlZTMxZmQtOTA1OS00ZTU4LThlYjctYzQ3ZWRlOTNlMjc2&state=CfDJ8DEQpM1bj61Kr5TRqW0a0y2ZmQTGIE_LIc-Zt7GiHkQ5bcYkYg5mbuo7Jl6YHNhoktLbD6B7HqZRZC5Q7oM3IUYgW-peKAqYFlMzpksmWMlZhKCfLdNtkc7uq7Lj8usN6Q67XUCkQ6vo8sNeLOaC-9STad0D86qLRUcaXZKEQTSytdvsrH34RUdsgLU6GeiiJ8Kk4E2JplQ5pnb5nYW4gbwryfeZNvQqaMiccs5Pd97BZNKxClaTglkVpAau2YwBNHvyM1V8cIwPoB_H3m9M_Tgf8rrRbGODBtmDHwdCElCvvuD20MwsGS3bPL8G3dCsX35oxXfVJmXR2faFLv0Ce1U&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0

The above URL is keep on loading.....

### Log:

```
2017-12-14 19:59:08.748 +08:00 [Debug] A data reader was disposed.
2017-12-14 19:59:08.749 +08:00 [Debug] Closing connection to database '"auth.Brown"' on server '"."'.
2017-12-14 19:59:08.750 +08:00 [Debug] Closed connection to database '"auth.Brown"' on server '"."'.
2017-12-14 19:59:08.752 +08:00 [Information] Clearing 0 tokens
2017-12-14 19:59:38.757 +08:00 [Information] Entity Framework Core "2.0.1-rtm-125" initialized '"PersistedGrantDbContext"' using provider '"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"' with options: "MigrationsAssembly=brown.auth.v2 "
2017-12-14 19:59:38.767 +08:00 [Debug] Opening connection to database '"auth.Brown"' on server '"."'.
2017-12-14 19:59:38.769 +08:00 [Debug] Opened connection to database '"auth.Brown"' on server '"."'.
2017-12-14 19:59:38.771 +08:00 [Debug] Executing DbCommand [Parameters=["@__UtcNow_0='?'"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"
""SELECT [x].[Key], [x].[ClientId], [x].[CreationTime], [x].[Data], [x].[Expiration], [x].[SubjectId], [x].[Type]
FROM [PersistedGrants] AS [x]
WHERE [x].[Expiration] < @__UtcNow_0"
2017-12-14 19:59:38.795 +08:00 [Information] Executed DbCommand ("23"ms) [Parameters=["@__UtcNow_0='?'"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"
""SELECT [x].[Key], [x].[ClientId], [x].[CreationTime], [x].[Data], [x].[Expiration], [x].[SubjectId], [x].[Type]
FROM [PersistedGrants] AS [x]
WHERE [x].[Expiration] < @__UtcNow_0"
2017-12-14 19:59:38.796 +08:00 [Debug] A data reader was disposed.
2017-12-14 19:59:38.797 +08:00 [Debug] Closing connection to database '"auth.Brown"' on server '"."'.
2017-12-14 19:59:38.798 +08:00 [Debug] Closed connection to database '"auth.Brown"' on server '"."'.
2017-12-14 19:59:38.799 +08:00 [Information] Clearing 0 tokens
2017-12-14 20:00:08.799 +08:00 [Information] Entity Framework Core "2.0.1-rtm-125" initialized '"PersistedGrantDbContext"' using provider '"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"' with options: "MigrationsAssembly=brown.auth.v2 "
2017-12-14 20:00:08.801 +08:00 [Debug] Opening connection to database '"auth.Brown"' on server '"."'.
2017-12-14 20:00:08.802 +08:00 [Debug] Opened connection to database '"auth.Brown"' on server '"."'.
2017-12-14 20:00:08.803 +08:00 [Debug] Executing DbCommand [Parameters=["@__UtcNow_0='?'"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"
""SELECT [x].[Key], [x].[ClientId], [x].[CreationTime], [x].[Data], [x].[Expiration], [x].[SubjectId], [x].[Type]
FROM [PersistedGrants] AS [x]
WHERE [x].[Expiration] < @__UtcNow_0"
2017-12-14 20:00:08.813 +08:00 [Information] Executed DbCommand ("10"ms) [Parameters=["@__UtcNow_0='?'"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"
""SELECT [x].[Key], [x].[ClientId], [x].[CreationTime], [x].[Data], [x].[Expiration], [x].[SubjectId], [x].[Type]
FROM [PersistedGrants] AS [x]
WHERE [x].[Expiration] < @__UtcNow_0"
2017-12-14 20:00:08.816 +08:00 [Debug] A data reader was disposed.
2017-12-14 20:00:08.817 +08:00 [Debug] Closing connection to database '"auth.Brown"' on server '"."'.
2017-12-14 20:00:08.818 +08:00 [Debug] Closed connection to database '"auth.Brown"' on server '"."'.
2017-12-14 20:00:08.820 +08:00 [Information] Clearing 0 tokens
```

Comment: can you show the code for your login controller as well as the view it uses upon authentication?

Comment: Your log only contains messages about token cleanup. This pollutes the log. I would disable this in the development environment (EnableTokenCleanup = false) and I would definately set a larger value for TokenCleanupInterval (instead of 30 seconds).